# Attaching Member function of a class in pthread

Tags: c++, c

```
pthread_t thread1;
pthread_create(&thread1,NULL,.......,NULL);
// Here I want to attach a thread to a member function of class
```

How can I pass the member function of a class in the above code.

Comment: Don't forget to catch all exceptions. If a thread exits because an exception completely unwinds the threads stack your program is likely to terminate.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a free `extern "C"` function as a trampoline:

```
class foo
{
public:
    void *thread_func();
};

extern "C" void *thread_func(void *arg)
{
    return static_cast<foo *>(arg)->thread_func();
}

foo f;
pthread_create(..., thread_func, &f);
```